# How to download Window Server 2008 R2 hotfix

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2008-r2, ftp, sftp

when I enable SSL for my ftp site (running on Windows Server 2008 R2 and IIS 7.5) and try to upload a file (FileZilla) it keeps uploading same file again and again with following message,

> 550: The supplied message is incomplete. The signature was not
>   verified.

When I searched this issue I found following hotfix but it's no longer available,
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2888853/fix-the-supplied-message-is-incomplete-error-when-you-use-an-ftps-clie

Is there any other trusted place to download this?
Or any other method to fix this issue? Thanks.

**Update: These updates failed when I ran Windows update,**
[image]

Comment: That hotfix may have been included in one or more of the ordinary updates released for Windows 2008 R2.  Check the file versions, if you already have the same or later versions of the affected files then you don't need the hotfix and your problem is something else.  (I'm assuming your server is up to date with Windows Update.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks. I did a Windows update and 9 updates failed as show in update to question. How do I know whether the required hotfix is in one of failed updates or it was installed with successful updates? Can I reinstall failed updates? Thanks again

Comment: You need to check the file versions.  The hotfix article tells you what file versions the hotfix would have installed.  Compare these to the versions of the files on your server.  Regardless of the results, you should certainly resolve the problem with the other updates as a matter of urgency.  (Try rebooting and then installing them one at a time.)

Comment: ... keeping in mind that end of life for Server 2008 R2 is not all that far away either.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I have run the Windows Update several times and it says there are no more updates to install. When I checked the file versions as you had pointed out, I noticed these two files are not updated, Ftpconfigext.dll and Ftpsvc.dll (other DLLs have same file version and date as mentioned in the hotfix https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2888853/fix-the-supplied-message-is-incomplete-error-when-you-use-an-ftps-clie). 1) Is there a safe place to download these two DLLs? 2) Is it safe to replace existing DLLs manually? Thanks

Comment: The hotfix is no longer available for casual download, but you should still be able to obtain it by contacting Microsoft Support.  Look under "hotfix information" in the KB article for contact information.